# Column width is different on different computers

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I need to provide custom column width for my excel.  I'm achieving it with a `getColumn` method by setting a number of points to width property.

Main question is why on different computers I'm getting different column width both in pixels and points. Is it possible to have same value (at least in points) for all exported excels?

For example the width of column is set to 16 points: on first computer I got `15.36 points` and `176px`, on the second - `15.29 points` and `112px`.

Additional question: is it happening because of different monitor resolutions or because of excel settings?

Comment: Have a read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths). If the different computers have e.g. different font types, then this will change the apparent column width. Does that help at all?

Comment: To further elaborate: 16 points width will fit exactly "1234567890123456", but the width of that differs between e.g. Calibri and Arial, and will also vary with font size. So changing the Style "Normal" from Font size 11 to font size 12 will increase the pixel width for the same "16 point" width cell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths)):

1. Specify the style of your columns, e.g. `Normal`, and specify the `Font` and `Font Size` of that style on the source computer that creates the workbook.
2. Explicitly set the `Font` and `Font size` of `Normal` Style on the target computer's Excel when opening the file to match that of the source computer.

By doing this you will have matched styles on the source and target computers, and hence experience the same column width.

PS: I'm assuming here that you are not using any Style other than `Normal`. If you are, then you will of course need to approach these styles appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is different fonts available on each OS. Following by Ecma-376, widths and heights has digit size as a unit (`ch` or `em` unit from css). Setting sizes should work perfectly with an available font for all OS.